Using DeferredProcessing of Camera results in Error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'
I am using the new feature of DeferredProcessing of iOS 17 in my camera app
Here is my code
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import Photos

//DeferredProcessing

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate,AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
    
    var previewView : UIView!
    let captureButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    let thumbnailImageView = UIImageView()
    
    var boxView:UIView!
    var videoDataOutput: AVCaptureVideoDataOutput!
    var videoDataOutputQueue: DispatchQueue!
    var previewLayer:AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
    var captureDevice : AVCaptureDevice!
    var photoOuput: AVCapturePhotoOutput!
    let session = AVCaptureSession()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        previewView = UIView(frame: view.frame)
        previewView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        previewView.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFit
        view.addSubview(previewView)
        
        boxView = UIView(frame: view.frame)
        view.addSubview(boxView)
        
        // Create the central button at the bottom (rounded button)
        
        captureButton.backgroundColor = .white
        captureButton.layer.cornerRadius = 35 // Rounded with height/2
        captureButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        captureButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onClickMyButton(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(captureButton)
        
        // Create the image view at the bottom left (rounded image view)
        thumbnailImageView.backgroundColor = .white
        thumbnailImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 25 // Rounded with height/2
        thumbnailImageView.clipsToBounds = true
        thumbnailImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(thumbnailImageView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            captureButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            captureButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -20),
            captureButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70),
            captureButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70)
        ])
        
        // Set up constraints for the image view at the bottom left
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            thumbnailImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            thumbnailImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -20),
            thumbnailImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
            thumbnailImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
        ])
        
        setupAVCapture()
    }
    
    @objc func onClickMyButton(sender: UIButton){
        let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.jpeg])
        photoOuput.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
        
    }
    
    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishCapturingDeferredPhotoProxy deferredPhotoProxy: AVCaptureDeferredPhotoProxy?, error: (any Error)?) {
        if let error = error {
            print("Error capturing photo \(error)")
            return
        }
        
        let library = PHPhotoLibrary.shared()
        if let data = deferredPhotoProxy?.fileDataRepresentation() {
            library.performChanges {
                let request = PHAssetCreationRequest.forAsset()
                request.addResource(with: .photoProxy, data: data, options: nil)
            } completionHandler: { success, photoError in
                if let photoError = photoError {
                    print("Error \(photoError)")
                    return
                }
                
                debugPrint("Sucess")
                
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    func requestAndHandleImageRepresentations(asset: PHAsset, targetSize: CGSize, contentMode: PHImageContentMode) -> PHImageRequestID {
        let imagemanager = PHImageManager.default()
        let imageRequestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
        imageRequestOptions.allowSecondaryDegradedImage = true
        return imagemanager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: targetSize, contentMode: contentMode, options: imageRequestOptions) { resultImage, info in
            if let info = info {
                if (info[PHImageResultIsDegradedKey] != nil){
                    
                } else {
                    
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    
    func setupAVCapture(){
        session.beginConfiguration()
        session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo
        guard let device = AVCaptureDevice
            .default(AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera,
                     for: .video,
                     position: AVCaptureDevice.Position.back) else {
            return
        }
        captureDevice = device
        beginSession()
    }
    
    func beginSession(){
        var deviceInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput!
        
        do {
            deviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
            photoOuput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
            guard deviceInput != nil else {
                print("error: cant get deviceInput")
                return
            }
            
            if session.canAddInput(deviceInput) && session.canAddOutput(photoOuput){
                session.addInput(deviceInput)
                session.addOutput(photoOuput)
            }
            
            if(photoOuput.isAutoDeferredPhotoDeliverySupported){
                photoOuput.isAutoDeferredPhotoDeliveryEnabled = true
            }
            
            session.commitConfiguration()
            
            videoDataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
            videoDataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames=true
            videoDataOutputQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "VideoDataOutputQueue")
            videoDataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue:videoDataOutputQueue)
            
            if session.canAddOutput(videoDataOutput){
                session.addOutput(videoDataOutput)
            }
            
            videoDataOutput.connection(with: .video)?.isEnabled = true
            
            previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
            previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect
            
            let rootLayer = previewView.layer
            rootLayer.masksToBounds=true
            previewLayer.frame = rootLayer.bounds
            rootLayer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { //[weak self] in
                self.session.startRunning()
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            deviceInput = nil
            print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    func stopCamera(){
        session.stopRunning()
    }
    
}

I get Error saying
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[AVCapturePhotoOutput capturePhotoWithSettings:delegate:] If you specify a non-nil format dictionary in your settings, your delegate must respond to the selector captureOutput:didFinishProcessingPhoto:error:, or the deprecated captureOutput:didFinishProcessingPhotoSampleBuffer:previewPhotoSampleBuffer:resolvedSettings:bracketSettings:error:'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18936cf20 0x181272018 0x1a63d574c 0x10441e9f4 0x10441eae0 0x18b96531c 0x18b9651f4 0x18b965044 0x18be7c080 0x18be7d894 0x18b8a5eac 0x18b8a5954 0x18b7269e0 0x18b7281d4 0x18b730ecc 0x18b62384c 0x18b62176c 0x18b6213b0 0x18b622254 0x18933f834 0x18933f7c8 0x18933d298 0x18933c484 0x18933bcd8 0x1ce1ec1a8 0x18b97490c 0x18ba289d0 0x18bba2384 0x104423994 0x10442390c 0x104423a10 0x1ac9ede4c)
libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException


The exception message seems pretty clear.  You need to implement one of the required delegate functions. Preferably this one

@Paulw11 How can I use didFinishProcessingPhoto along with didFinishCapturingDeferredPhotoProxy?

It's up to you what you do in that delegate method, but it is required that you implement it with a non-nil format directory

@Paulw11 I did override didFinishProcessingPhoto but I still don't understand how didFinishProcessingPhoto will help didFinishCapturingDeferredPhotoProxy

It doesn't. It is simply a requirement that you have some implementation of that delegate method if you provide a non-nil format dictionary. It can be an empty function, but it must exist.
